# MQL 4 Boll reversal trading bot

Tags: mql4, mql

I would like to write this EA in MQL4

Maxposition 1, No stopless

**Sell perttern** Current price is more than Bool Upperband 5 Sigma sell Current price lower than 2 sigma boll lower band TP

**Buy puttern** Bool Lowerband 5 Sigma Buy 2 sigma boll Upper band TP

**Problem**
-int total=0; said unexpected token. I don't know how to fix.

-I ask if Ticket number has been idenityied?
-Last parenthese does not work } not all controle paths return a value.

-I asked chat GTP and source code based on program that I made but I cannot do it out. Please help me out. Thank you !!

```
    double waitBB,maisuu=0.01;
    datetime prevtime;
    input int Lotsize = 0.04

    int total=0;

     int start()
    {
     int orderPtn=0; //0:Nothing 1:Buy 2:Sell

     int errorcode;               // Error
     int ticket,ea_order_entry_Type=0,ea_order_MagicNo;  // Ticket Noentrytype,Magic Ｎｏ．
     double ea_order_stop_price=0,ea_order_good_price=0,ea_order_entry_price=0; //Stopless TP, Entry

//---

//Boll pricing rates
    double BB5UP = iBands(NULL,0,20,5,0,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_UPPER,0); //upper 5σ
    double BB5LO = iBands(NULL,0,20,5,0,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_LOWER,0); //lower 5σ

    double BB2UP = iBands(NULL,0,20,2,0,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_UPPER,0); //upper 2σ
    double BB2LO = iBands(NULL,0,20,2,0,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_LOWER,0); //lower 2σ

//***Buy and sell checker***//

//Bid price above the price of upper Boll 5σ and sell action
    if(BB5UP \> Bid)
    {
    orderPtn=2;
    }
//Ask price below the price of lower Boll 5σ and buy action
    else if(BB5LO \< Ask)
    {
    orderPtn=1;
    }
// otherwise nothing to do
    else
    {
    orderPtn=0;
    }

//Buy action
    if((orderPtn==1) || waitBB\>0 )
    {
//lowerband 5σ equal or lower, buy
    if((BB5LO \> Ask || BB5LO == Ask ))
    {
    orderPtn=1;
    waitBB=0;
    }else{
    orderPtn=0;
    waitBB=1;  
    }
    }
//Sell action
    if((orderPtn==2) || waitBB\<0 )
    {
//   upperband 5σ equal or upper, sell
    if((BB5UP \< Bid  || BB5UP  == Ask ))
    {
    orderPtn=2;
    waitBB=0;
    }else{
    orderPtn=0;
    waitBB=-1;  
    }
    }  
//***sell buy positon check ***//
    int totalOrders = 0;
    totalOrders = OrdersTotal();

    if(totalOrders == 1)

    {
//If I have a position, don't have a position
    waitBB=0;
    }

//Entry point
    else if(totalOrders == 0 && orderPtn \> 0)
    {

    if(BB5LO \> PERIOD_CURRENT  ||BB5LO == PERIOD_CURRENT )
    {
         OrderSend(NULL, OP_BUY, Lotsize, Ask, 20, Close[0] + 0.5, 0, "Buy", ea_order_MagicNo, 0, Red);
    }

    else if(BB5UP \< PERIOD_CURRENT  || BB5UP == PERIOD_CURRENT )

    {
    OrderSend(NULL, OP_SELL, Lotsize, Bid, 20, Close\[0\] + 0.5, 0, "sell", ea_order_MagicNo, 0, Red);

    }

    else if(totalOrders == 1 && orderPtn \> 0)

    {

    if (OrderType() == OP_BUY || OrderType() == OP_SELL)

    {
         if (OrderProfit() < 0) 
         {
             
         }
            
         else if (OrderProfit() > 0) 
            
         {    
              if(BB2LO < PERIOD_CURRENT)
              {    
                   bool result =  OrderClose(ticket ,Lotsize, PERIOD_CURRENT, 20,Red);
               }

          else if(BB2UP > PERIOD_CURRENT)

               { 
                     bool result = OrderClose(ticket ,Lotsize, PERIOD_CURRENT, 20, Blue);
               }  
          }

          else
          {
                Print("Failed to close position: ", GetLastError());
          }
    
    }
    
    }
      
              
      ea_order_MagicNo=33;  //MagicNo33
    
            ticket = OrderSend(   // New order
            NULL,                     // Pair
            ea_order_entry_Type,      // Order type [OP_BUY / OP_SELL]
            Lotsize,                   // Lots (0.01
            ea_order_entry_price,     // Order price rate
            20,                       // Slip
            ea_order_stop_price,      // Stop rate
            ea_order_good_price,      // Limit rate
            "Ordered ",              // Order comment
            ea_order_MagicNo,         // MagicNo
            0,                        // order limited time
            clrRed                    // order icon color
          );
                
      if ( ticket == -1)           // order error
      {
         errorcode = GetLastError();      // error code 
         if( errorcode != ERR_NO_ERROR)   // error producted 
         {
             printf("Order Error");
         }
      }
      else 
        {    // order executed 
         Print("Order Done",ticket);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if you've forgotten the 'comma and point thing' (semicolon) after 0.04:

```
input int Lotsize = 0.04

int total=0;
```

`Not all paths return a value`:
You made a lot of `if`-statements. Your function is probably an `int()` function, so compiler checks whether an integer is returned as a result of execution of that function. (I'm on my phone but and it's hard to break apart your code in that tiny screen).
If compiler finds any `if`-statement that is not returning the expected type, it throws an error like you see.
Better solution IMO:

1. At the start of the function, declare a result variable with a default value.
2. All `if`-statements can modify that default value.
3. At the end of the function, return the variable, whether modified or not.

Cheers!